# Error: Missing credentials in config - /nodeapp/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:31

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm pulling objects using `s3.listObjects()` function from the AWS-SDK and I keep getting the following error:

```
/nodeapp/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:31
```

Followed by

```
Error: Missing credentials in config
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/nodeapp/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/util.js:863:34)
at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:186:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)
```

This doesn't add up because I have a different route (downloadParam) that retrieves an object from S3 without giving me this error. Additionally, when I log out the objects retrieved from `downloadResults` route, it appears the objects were retrieved with no issues but i'll still get this error.

I have spent hours on this issue and I can't seem to figure out why this is occurring. I have pasted by code for both routes below, the one that works and the one that doesn't. From what I've gleaned online, this appears to be more of a code issue than an AWS-SDK credentials issue.

```
  downloadParam: function(app, s3){
app.use('/api', apiRoutes)

apiRoutes.get('/download-param-file', function(req, res, next){
 res.set({'Content-Type':'text/csv'})
  s3.getObject({Bucket: 'some-bucket', Key: 'some-key' + req.query.fileName}, function(err, file){

    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return next(err);
    } else {
      return res.send(file.Body.toString());
    }
  })
})
},

downloadResults: function(app, s3){
app.use('/api', apiRoutes)

apiRoutes.get('/download-results-file', function(req, res, next){
   res.set({'Content-type': 'application/zip'})

   var params = {
    Bucket: 'some-bucket',
    Delimiter: '/',
    Prefix: 'some-key'
    };


   var filesArray = []
   var files = s3.listObjects(params).createReadStream()
   var xml = new XmlStream(files)
   xml.collect('Key')

   xml.on('endElement: Key', function(item) {
     filesArray.push(item['$text'].substr(params.Prefix.length))
    })

   xml.on('end', function() {

    res.send(zip(filesArray, req.query.jobName,  params))


  })        
})
}
```

As of right now `downloadParams` works as expected but `downloadResults` does not. Any help would be tremendously appreciated.

[This link seems solve an issue similar to mine](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/936)

Comment: Where is apiRoutes defined?

Comment: At the top of my routes.js file @JoachimBrandonLeBlanc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not authenticating the call. The bucket does not have permissions to list objects without authentication, whereas it does have permission to download specific files without authentication.

See the [Amazon Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/global-config-object.html) on adding credentials [safely](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-credentials-node.html) to the instance.

Essentially,

```
var creds = AWS.Credentials();
creds.accessKeyId = 'AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE';
creds.secretAccessKey = 'wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY';

AWS.config.credentials = creds;
```

Comment: I added permissions for my bucket for grantee "everyone" for listing and upload/delete. Still no luck. Any further suggestions?

Comment: I'm already authenticating the call in my server.js by using aws-config. What am I missing? `const s3 = new AWS.S3(awsConfig({
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
  apiVersion: '2006-03-01' })
);`

Comment: What's that `awsConfig` function? The [S3 constructor takes an object](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html).

Comment: Thank you, I finally understood what you were referring to.